# Python selenium работа с памятью

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

Есть парсер selenium + phantom js.

Запускается через multiprocessing.dummy, map. 
Все хорошо, запускает 4 процесса и начинает работать.

В диспетчере задач win соответсвенно появляется 4 процесса Phantom js, у которых начинает расти потребление памяти, и в конце парсер падает в MemoryError.

Можно как то влиять на этот процесс? Высвобождать память может... 
Я, кроме как перезапускаться после краша ничего не придумал пока

Comment: Интересно, какое ограничение на размер оперативной памяти, какая разрядность ОС, и что же такое делает парсер, что постоянно память потребляет, видео что-ли качает в память :)

Comment: На работе на внутреннем сайте после логина появляется форма ввода для ID, парсер заходит-передает ид, переключает фрейм, переключает страницу, забирает инфу, возвращается на главную, вставляет новый ид и тд. 15 тыщ ИД нужно пробежать. ОС 64 разрядная, 6Гб ОЗУ..4 процесса набирают примерно по Гб памяти и MemoryError

Comment: Питон или PhantomJs наверное 32-х битные... Интересно, а если вместо PhantomJs какой-нибудь другой браузер попробовать? Я думаю вот эта проблема к вашей относится: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14143

Comment: Пробовал через хром - та же беда. Спасибр, почитаю че там :)